# Admin on GAE and django

Tags: django, google-app-engine, session-cookies

Im developing a google app engine and django based site and i'm tring to figure out what's
the best approach to solve the problem, the site requirments are as follows:

1. There must be a super administrator who's only task is to create second level administrators and assign them to a group.
2. Second level administrators can create regular users and those users are assigded to the same group from the admin that created them.
3. Regular users don't do much besides login and logout.

I've been reading and i think i can solve 1 with the (login: admin) GAE feature for app.yaml.

I don't want to use google accounts neigther openid because second level admins are
the only allowed to create users.

For 3. Is it possible to use django session utility to handle regular users ?

I'd appreciate suggestion for a particular point or the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1:
login:admin in app.yaml will prevent users that are not associated with your GAE project from visiting that URL or set of URLs. Any user associated with your GAE production project is an admin. You can create additional filtering inside the application by confirming the username that they are currently logged in with.

```
from google.appengine.api import users
user = users.get_current_user()
email = user.email()
```

For 3:
I am not sure, we ended up rolling our own.